# Need Help with queries (views) in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an application that records weight of a bin holding items in inventory into a Microsoft Access Table Like so:

```
Id(AutoNumber)  Timestamp       Weight
-------------------------------------
1                Jan 1           1
2                Jan 2           1

3                Jan 3           2
4                Jan 4           2
5                Jan 5           2

6                Jan 6           3
7                Jan 7           3
8                Jan 7           3

9                Jan 8           2
10               Jan 8           2

11               Jan 9           7

12               Jan 10          4
13               Jan 10          4
```

Note that weight may change from day to day. Sometimes the weight will not change for days. I want to output a report listing only the weight when it has changed and not repeat the row if the weight does not change, like so (ID field not necessary):

```
Timestamp       Weight
----------------------
  Jan 1           1

  Jan 3           2

  Jan 6           3

  Jan 8           2

  Jan 9           7

  Jan 10          4
```

I can do this using code either in VB or in an Access Module, writing it to a temp table etc. But is there a way to do this just using SQL queries (views), including subqueries? I am thinking I should be able to write one query using GROUP By clause to get the 'FIRST' item and another query to join with the first one, but have this feeling this cannot be done at all without writing some code. (This application will be on a web site - Access is not good with temporary tables for multiple users)

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.dt, o.value from table1   o
where not exists (select top 1 t.dt, t.value from table1 t where t.dt < o.dt )
union 
select o.dt, o.value from table1   o
where exists (select top 1 t.dt, t.value from table1 t where t.dt = (o.dt - 1) and 
t.value <> o.value)
```

Note: I am assuming dt as the datetime field, value as the weight field.
You can base your query off this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use your `timestamp` column for ordering because as far as I can tell 
it doesn't provide a key. Given multiple `netwt` values for the same `timestamp` e.g.

```
80001   '2009-07-22 09:28:23'   0.55
80002   '2009-07-22 09:28:23'   0.22
80003   '2009-07-22 09:28:23'   0.99
```

you can't know the order without the `id` column.

As it stands the `id` column seems to show the order but this is possibly an unsafe assumption (e.g. it is possible to `INSERT` an explicit `id` value which could be out of sequence).

[BTW `TIMESTAMP` is a reserved word for the Access database enging, SQL Standards SQL-92, ODBC, SQL Server Future, etc and should therefore be avoided as a data element name.]

The following uses the id column for odering to determine whether the 'next' netwt value is different:

```
SELECT T3.id, T3.[timestamp], T3.netwt
  FROM table1 AS T3
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT MIN(T2.id)
                 FROM table1 AS T1, table1 AS T2
                WHERE T1.id < T2.id
                      AND T1.netwt <> T2.netwt
                GROUP 
                   BY T1.id
               HAVING MIN(T2.id) = T3.id
              );
```